# Swift push segue without trigger

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to push to another view controller but without button or any action..
The thing is, in view1 I check if user is logged in, and if not, it should go to view2(login/signup) controller..

I have tried with:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Parse

class MainMenu: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkIfLoggedIn()
  }

  func checkIfLoggedIn() {
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    println("\(currentUser)")
    if currentUser != nil {
      println("User is already logged in, and stays on main menu")
    }
    else {
      println("User goes to Login page")
      //self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPage") as! LogInPage
      //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("needToLogin", sender: self)
    }
  }

  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
```

but it does not work(needs some action I believe; like pressing button)

Thanks :D

Comment: No, this does not need some action. Where are you calling this method? Can you post the entire code of your view controller? If you call this in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, this might be too early.

Comment: @Glorfindel I called it in viewDidLoad(edited question - whole function is there)

Comment: Can you try moving it to `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @JHof No, you do not need to instantiate it when pushing it through `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Only when you're pushing it on the NavigationController directly.

Comment: it works now that I have moved it to viewDidAppear! thanks!